# Porting Linux kernel 2.6 to new MIPS board

Tags: linux-kernel, mips, cross-compiling, embedded-linux

I wanna port Linux kernel 2.6.x to new MIPS board. Unfortunatelly, I can't find good actual documentation with step by step explaination. Hope, you'll help me. Paper books are OK too.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Check Openwrt for a board with a similar processor.

Answer (score 1):

First, get your hands on a MIPS [toolchain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toolchain). You're going to need it to compile the kernel. I've used [buildroot](http://buildroot.uclibc.org/) a few times, including for building a MIPS toolchain.

But buildroot offers a lot more than just that:

> Buildroot can generate any or all of a
>   cross-compilation toolchain, a root
>   filesystem, **a kernel image** and a
>   bootloader image. Buildroot is useful
>   mainly for people working with small
>   or embedded systems, using various CPU
>   architectures (x86, ARM, MIPS,
>   PowerPC, etc.) : it automates the
>   building process of your embedded
>   system and eases the cross-compilation
>   process.

If you would like to do this process manually, I suggest you take a look at [this](http://www.ailis.de/~k/archives/19-ARM-cross-compiling-howto.html). It's not for MIPS but it shows the generic formula (you'll probably have to find and apply MIPS patches to the Kernel before compiling it). Try buildroot, it does all of this automagically!

I must also recommend reading [Jun Sun's Linux MIPS Porting Guide](http://linux.junsun.net/porting-howto/).

Comment: Thank you, but I have some experience with all this tools. I'm asking about how to write code for initialization of IRQ, RAM, etc. Something like this (http://www.linux-mips.org/wiki/Linux/MIPS_Porting_Guide), but more fresh and detailed. Thank you!

Comment: I edited my answer to add a reference to Jun Sun's Linux MIPS Porting Guide in case you didn't saw it yet.

Comment: karlphillip, but this is the same document :( Yup, I know about Google! I've been googling for few days without any real results. Anyway, thank you!